# What is a single word meaning "authoritative source of knowledge"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that means authoritative source of knowledge.

The word would preferably be a noun and could refer to a group of people or a collection of knowledge.  Additionally it'd be strongly preferred if the word would not be a derivative of encyclopedia.

Comment: I think the word you are looking for is "@FumbleFingers" :-)

Comment: Not an answer, but contrast with _credible_: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/credible

Comment: An Expert is called to testify due to their authoritative source of knowledge.

Comment: I was looking for a word similar to the Question, and ended up using the word **Almanac**

Comment: Not a good choice. An almanac is "An annual calendar containing important dates and statistical information such as astronomical data and tide tables." While an almanac might be authoritative (or it might not), not all authorities are almanacs. http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/almanac

Comment: You should say "According to HotLicks ..."

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could simply call it an *authority*, and that could stand for a human guru or a tome.

Comment: I think "authority" is pretty much the standard term for what you're describing. Some of the other answers herer might be more appropriate in specific contexts.

Answer (score 8):

My choice would be [cornbread ninja's](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/61400/10041), but s/he beat me to it.  *[Authority](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/authority)*:

> **5.** an accepted source of information, advice, etc.
>   **7.** an expert on a subject: *He is an authority on baseball.*

I like the word *[pundit](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pundit)*, not least because it's a coveted [Stack Exchange badge](https://english.stackexchange.com/badges/24/pundit).  Other words for learned and authoritative people could be *[guru](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/guru)*, *[savant](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/savant)*, or *[sage](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sage)*.

There's also *[cognoscenti](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cognoscenti)*:

> ***plural noun***, **singular -te**
>   persons who have superior knowledge and understanding of a particular field, especially in the fine arts, literature, and world of fashion.

Comment: Similarly, "guru".

Comment: I thought of *savant*, too.

Comment: I would not go with *pundit*, as in the U.S. the sense of "commentator" prevails— and with it, the somewhat negative image of the "talking heads" on television news networks who deliver only those facts which service their opinions.

Answer (score 6):

The *canon* is the collective term for those authorities which are indisputable (originally a religious term, but now general).  So a book may be *canonical*.  I don't think either should be applied to people, though, to avoid confusion.

Comment: True, though I think it's mostly limited to religious and literary contexts. i.e. you can talk about "the Christian canon" or the "Hindu canon", and you can talk about "the Star Trek canon". But I don't think I've ever heard someone refer to "the wood-working canon" or "the particle physics canon".

Comment: @Jay I refer to "canonical data sets" all the time, to mean the set of data that we know to be trusted, true, clean, reliable, and the source by which other sets of data are modified to become so. I also use it for other situations in technology where I mean to connote "the approved and proper set".

Comment: @ErikE Yes, it's used in IT in general to refer to an authoritative source. In IT it can also mean the "standard" or "approved" something, like "canonical date format". As an IT person myself, I'm not sure how I skipped that. I'm not aware of it having similar meaning in other fields -- "a canonical list of elementary particles" ?

Comment: @Jay The elementary particle list is short and is closed--there aren't really multiple sources telling us different things about it that may or may not be true. If there were, then perhaps it would make more sense. Also note that music can be a canon, meaning a melody is repeated at an interval after a certain period of time. Most people know of canon in D by Pachelbel...

Comment: @ErikE This page, http://www.enotes.com/topic/List_of_particles, lists dozens of subatomic particles, including many classed as "hypothetical", so I don't think it's really valid to say that the list is "short and closed". Of course that would be a reason to NOT refer to a canonical list, at least in the present tense. But in any case, my point wasn't to question whether physicists talk specifically about a "canonical list of subatomic particles", but rather whether they talk about ANYTHING being "canonical". I don't know. (continued)

Comment: ... I am unfamiliar with the musical term you describe. From what you say this appears to be a completely different definition of the word.

Comment: @Jay Good point about the particles. Anyway about the music, have you heard of "canon at the octave"? Specifically, for piano? It means to lay down a "canonical" melody, then what comes after it repeats what has been laid down. In the sense of "that which is to be copied; the source" it has the same meaning.

Comment: @ErikE I'm not familiar with the term -- not surprising, I'm not that knowledgeable about music. Okay, as you describe it now, I see the connection. I misunderstood your first description.

Comment: [Anatomy of a Musical Canon](http://jan.ucc.nau.edu/~tas3/canonanatomy.html)

Answer (score 1):

[Maven](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/maven)

> One who is experienced or knowledgeable

More so than "expert," this has the connotation of someone who actively concerns themselves with the subject.

Comment: Please follow the [community guidelines on citations](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). However, answers which merely copy others' work -- even if *correctly* referenced -- may be removed. Please add some original editorial comment on your chosen word. (Previous, older, answers may not have had the current guidelines to follow, but they are no longer necessarily a good model.)

Answer (score 0):

> **Oracle**
>
> a person or thing regarded as an infallible authority or guide on
>   something

[p.305, *The Oxford Dictionary of Difficult Words*, edited by Archie Hobson]

Comment: Hi Mike, welcome to EL&U. Please note, the system has flagged your answer for deletion as "low-quality because of its **length** and **content**." An answer on this site is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. I suggest you [edit] your answer - for example, noting the word's etymology or giving some examples of usage. For further guidance, see [answer] and take the EL&U **[Tour]** :-)

Comment: PS I think *oracle* is a useful addition, so I've edited your answer to add the source I found for your definition. Mike, it's essential that you cite the source of any words you use that aren't your own. Not only does that add *authority* to your answer, it also means you're acknowledging the original author for their effort/research, and avoids any suggestion of *plagiarism*.

Answer (score -1):

It would depend on how you want to use the word.  The first thing that popped into my mind was *mentor*.

Comment: A mentor is a sponsor, which is somewhat different from an "authoritative source."  Also, we'd likely to rely on something more substantial than whatever pops into your mind.  A reference that explains the reason for the popping would help.  BTW, I'm not the downvoter.